# preg_match_all regex fails when there are spaces

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

I'm trying to get the image urls from html source code using the following regex, but it fails when the image url has spaces in it. For example this url:

```
<img src="http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Entertainment/876/493/kazantsev pink bikini reuters.jpg?ve=1&amp;tl=1" alt="kazantsev pink bikini reuters.jpg" itemprop="image">

$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

This gives me back the following.
http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Entertainment/876/493/kazantsev

Is there a way to match any character including whitespace? Or is it something I have to set in the php configuration?

Comment: `.*` includes spaces too. The problem is not here and regexp works fine. Show the text you are trying to apply it to. It might happen that there is not a space, but `'` or `"` (they are not supposed to be in url at all)

Comment: You can simplify your regexp : `<img.*?src=["|'](.*)["|']`
This one matches your whole URL. You can use [regexp simulators](http://regex101.com/) to test your expressions.

Comment: I'm trying to post the string here to see if there's some other reason it won't work, but I'm having trouble with stackoverflow truncating it, is there a tag I can put in the comments when pasting in code? <img src="http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Entertainment/876/493/kazantsev pink bikini reuters.jpg?ve=1&amp;tl=1" alt="kazantsev pink bikini reuters.jpg" itemprop="image">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues with your regular expression.

First, you are trying to use the concatenation operator (`'.'`) to join both parts of your expression together ( *this is not necessary* ). Secondly, you don't need to use the alternation operator `|` inside of your character classes.

The dot `.` will match any character except newline sequence. It is a possibility that these tags could possibly include line breaks since they are located in HTML source. You could use the `s` (dotall) modifier which forces the dot to match any character including line breaks or use a negated character class meaning match any character **except**.

Using the `s` (*dotall*) modifier:

```
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*src=(["\'])(.*?)\1/si';
```

Using a negated character class `[^ ]`

```
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*src=(["\'])([^"\']*)\1/i';
```

Although, it is much easier to use a parser such as [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to grab the results.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
   $urls[] = $node->getAttribute('src');
}

print_r($urls);
```

Comment: This is better, I'll try that after I fix the first problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the regex and also for the alternative which is much cleaner and probably faster.  And thanks very much for the easy to understand explanation. Just for future reference how to you incorporate the s (dotall) modifier you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm going to rework the code with the dom solution you suggested.

Comment: Just implemented it, seems much faster.